# Не работает временная таблица

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

Хочу сделать временную таблицу и ,в общем то, ее и вызвать.

вот сам код

```
with su as (
     select *
     from table t 
     where t."Point_ID"  = '66678990' or "Point_ID"='ll9090')


select *
from su
```

Но выдается ошибка:

SQL Error [42P01]: ОШИБКА: отношение "su" не существует
Позиция: 16

Вроде делаю, все как по документации написано.

Comment: `with` - это не временная таблица. Вы судя по всему делаете два запроса, а нужно чтоб все что вы написали выполнять в одном запросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что dbeaver не умеет работь с кодом, у которого есть пробелы **между строк** (пустые строки). Так что надо убрать их.

Comment: класс! Большое спасибо